# Uber Carthage swift ridesClient.requestRide gives ride=nil

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uber-api

I am trying to integrate Uber SDK with my current iOS app.

I have Xcode :- 8.1 iOS :-10.1 and swift version :- 3.0

I have done setup for "Carthage" for Uber integration.

i am calling requestRide method and its always giving ride=nil

```
let parameterBuilder = RideParametersBuilder()

parameterBuilder.setProductID("a1111c8c-c720-46c3-8534-2fcdd730040d")

let pickupLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 37.770, longitude: -122.466)
parameterBuilder.setPickupLocation(pickupLocation, nickname: "California Academy of Sciences")
let dropoffLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 37.791, longitude: -122.405)
parameterBuilder.setDropoffLocation(dropoffLocation, nickname: "Pier 39")

let ridesClient = RidesClient()

ridesClient.requestRide(parameterBuilder.build(), completion: { ride, response in
}
```

Please help me.

i stuck here not able to execute my project. any suggestion will be useful for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you enable debugging and provide any error details?

Comment: ride-nil-
response.statusCode-401-
response.data-Optional(<OS_dispatch_data: data[0x1762c7c0] = { leaf, size = 122, buf = 0x17616740 }>)-
response.data.datastring-Optional({"message":"This endpoint requires at least one of the following scopes: request, request.delegate","code":"unauthorized"})-

Comment: here is my requestRide() method output.

Comment: It looks like you haven't implemented sso and authorized the 'request' scope in your token. See more here: https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/api/ios#native-login-with-uber-sso

Comment: my plist :- <key>UberCallbackURIs</key>
 <array>
  <dict>
   <key>URIString</key>
   <string>swiftsdk://connect</string>
   <key>UberCallbackURIType</key>
   <string>General</string>
  </dict>
  <dict>
   <key>URIString</key>
   <string>swiftsdk://connect</string>
   <key>UberCallbackURIType</key>
   <string>AuthorizationCode</string>
  </dict>
 </array>

Comment: <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
 <array>
  <string>uber</string>
  <string>uberauth</string>
 </array>

Comment: <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
 <array>
  <dict>
   <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
   <string>Editor</string>
   <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
   <array>
    <string>swiftsdk://uberSSO</string>
   </array>
  </dict>
 </array>

Comment: Here is my plist for uber. my call back url is :- "swiftsdk://connect"

Comment: can you tell me now where i am wrong.

Comment: You should remove your credentials from the above.

Comment: thank u Dustin Whittle for your suggestion.